# How do you enable the Administrative Tools in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

How do you enable the Administrative Tools in Windows 8.1?

Specifically the Powershell ISE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I enable Administrative Tools?

> Administrative Tools in Windows are system management apps to change important settings of operating system. They include the Disk Management tool, Local Group Policy, Local Users and Group Management, Computer Management, Services and many other important management console tools. By default, they are hidden from the Start screen in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. To access these tools, you need to use the Control Panel. There you will find them under Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative tools. If you are using them frequently, you might want to show them on the Start screen.
>
> To show Administrative Tools on the Start screen in Windows 8.1 Update, you need to do the following:
>
> 1. Go to the Start Screen.
> 2. Press the Win + I shortcut on the keyboard. The settings charm will appear on the right.
> 3. Click the Tiles item. It will open the additional settings pane:
> 4. Move the Administrative tools slider there from left to right to turn them on:
>
> You are done. The whole set of Administrative tools will be shown on
> the Start screen inside the Apps view.

The link below contains screenshots for each step.

Source [How to display Administrative tools on the Start screen in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-display-administrative-tools-on-the-start-screen-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/)

---

#### How do I start the PowerShell ISE

> **How to Start Windows PowerShell ISE on Windows 8**
>
> Windows PowerShell ISE is an administrative tool in Windows 8. The
> procedure that you use to start Windows PowerShell ISE depends on
> whether the Show Administrative Tools setting is on or off.
>
> *From the Start screen*
>
> - On the Start screen, type PowerShell_ISE and then click powershell_ise.
> - If Show Administrative Tools is on, on the Start screen, type ISE and then click Windows PowerShell ISE.
>
> To pin a Windows PowerShell ISE shortcut to the taskbar, right-click
> the powershell_ise or Windows PowerShell ISE app tile, and then on the
> app bar, click Pin to taskbar.
>
> *From the desktop*
>
> - Move the cursor to the top right corner of the screen and then click Search.
>
>   Type PowerShell_ISE and then click powershell_ise.
> - If Show Administrative Tools is on, move the cursor to the top right corner of the screen and then click Search.
>
>   Type ISE and then click Windows PowerShell ISE.
>
> *At the Command Prompt*
>
> - In Cmd.exe, Windows PowerShell, or Windows PowerShell ISE, to start Windows PowerShell ISE, type:
>
>   PowerShell_ISE
>
> You can also use the parameters of the PowerShell_ISE.exe program to
> customize the session. For more information, see PowerShell_ISE.exe
> Console Help.
>
> *With Administrator permissions ("Run as administrator")*
>
> - From the Start screen, type PowerShell_ISE, right-click the powershell_ise app tile, and in the app bar, click Run as
>   administrator.
> - On the desktop, move the cursor to the upper right corner, click Search, type PowerShell_ISE, right-click the powershell_ise app tile,
>   and in the app bar, click Run as administrator.
> - At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type:
>
>   Start-Process PowerShell_ISE -Verb RunAs

Source [Starting Windows PowerShell on Windows 8 and Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847889.aspx)